# Javascript is changing style of all elements instead of one

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the background color of div one by one with an interval of 1sec
but my code changes the color of all divs after one 1sec

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar" id="bar-1"></div>
  <div class="bar" id="bar-2"></div>
  .
  .
  <div class="bar" id="bar-100"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  let elem = document.getElementById('bar-' + i);

  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting all the timeouts at the same time, so they all finish 1 second later.

You need to use different timeouts for each element. Multiply the timeout by the index.

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  let elem = document.getElementById('bar-' + i);

  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }, 1000 * i);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar" id="bar-1">1</div>
  <div class="bar" id="bar-2">2</div>
  <div class="bar" id="bar-3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I always get stuck in asynchronous stuff.

Comment: note that this solution will drift, if you care about precision, as the size of the number of elements increases since there's a fraction of a second delay before `setTimeout` is called again. And a lot of memory could be used since it needs to story 100 or more element references while waiting for the timeout to be executed

Comment: @Samathingamajig Unless there's a huge number of elements, the drift is negligible -- users can't tell the difference between 1 second and 1.01 second. And remember that the timeout functions don't guarantee precise timing to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code executes all the `elem.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';` lines at approximately the same time, since `setTimeout` doesn't wait for the previous execution to finish before starting its timer.

The following code should achieve your desired result:

```js
let i = 1;
const itv = setInterval(() => {
  if (i > 3) return clearInterval(itv); // change this number to be 100, 3 is for demo
  const elem = document.getElementById('bar-' + i);
  elem.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  i++;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar" id="bar-1">1</div>
  <div class="bar" id="bar-2">2</div>
  <div class="bar" id="bar-3">3</div>
</div>
```